# How to find best practice for task x at a certain point in time?

Tags: software-design, application-planning

Informatics constantly improves and the "best" way to do task x changes over time, often when you search for something you haven't done yourself yet, you are encountered by "oldschool" methods where there is a more modern way already. But because it has been around longer the older method produces more results on search enginges because it was clicked more often...

How to find best practice for task x at a certain point in time?

PS: At the moment my goal is to develop an web-application with a browserfrontend which is supported by serverside algorithms for analysing some data, but I thought asking in a more general way might help others with the same issue in other fields.

Comment: Is this even answerable ?

Comment: I hope so, I mean somehow some people produce great software, where/how do they acquire the knowledge? What language, framework etc. is best for their usecase?

Comment: *"where/how do they acquire the knowledge"* by practice.